# Minimum recommended thickness for self-leveling concrete topping (skim coat)

Tags: concrete, flooring, self-leveling-concrete, resurfacing

I'd like to resurface an already somewhat level but tarnished concrete floor with a self-leveling cement-based compound and to raise the floor level as little as possible; I've found compounds like Mira 6700 where the manufacturer specified layer thickness starts at 1 mm, so presumably the compound should be able to level itself even as a thin layer. The question is, what would be the downsides of  using a thin layer? I would properly prime the floor and use a concrete densifier after, and the floors would have minimal traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only drawback I can think of is that self-leveling products don't tend to feather themselves to a knife edge. They tend to leave an edge similar to what you'd see with a puddle of water on a glass table, with a bead of approximately 1/8 inch thick. So if your layer doesn't cover the entire floor you'll need to deal with that by tooling at partial cure, or by skimming with another product such as a vinyl concrete patch. Otherwise I have no concerns.

Be aware that most such products are not intended as a finished floor. They're somewhat soft and can gouge and wear easily.

Comment: I agree self leveling is ok but some minor finish work helps+

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My plan is to use a lithium silicate densifier as a finish.

Comment: Interested in the outcome of this, I have a similar situation and it's somewhat high traffic, but I don't want to give up much head space. Was the silicate sufficient to keep it strong?

Comment: It generally didn't work; the densifier was not enough to make it water-resistant, but it also seemed to prevent "liquid glass" (which I ended up using) from being able to penetrate the concrete, so the result was a floor that can't be properly cleaned. If I could do it over, I'd definitely try using a linseed oil based product instead (I didn't do that to avoid the smell).

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting a 1/8" edge, you are mixing it too thick.  It needs to look like it's mixed too thin, and spread it out. It will dry and you'll get the feather edge you want.

Comment: I disagree. Folks think this stuff should be watery. It isn't. It's more like warm peanut butter. Be sure to follow the mix recipe accurately or you'll end up with powder. I'll withhold a downvote since I haven't used every available product, but the ones I have are _barely_ liquid.

Comment: My experience with LevelQuik RS is that the recipe on the bag makes a dry mix that doesn't flow enough to actually level. Especially in dry California. I did everything I could to make it work as specified. Primed to spec ahead of time, fast workflow, no interruptions. It wasn't self-leveling at all. It had a visible crown where poured, and lots of surface tension. I was forced to trowel it around quite a bit, which sped up evaporation, exacerbating the problem. Talked to a pro-tiler who uses same but a much wetter mix, and adding just a little more water made it work so so so much better.